# How can I paint through a mesh while weight painting ? [Blender 2.8]

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

So I found a few questions like this already, but none of them solves the problem in the 2.8 version of blender. How can I weight paint through a mesh in front view for example? In the image below I tried using the show x-Ray option and the front face only option, but none of them works.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

In the latest Blender version it looks like you need to open the *N* panel, click on the *Too*l tab and in *Brush Settings*:

- *Advanced* > disable *Front Faces Only*
- *Falloff* > switch from *Sphere* to *Project*
- *Front Face Falloff* > disable the option

Comment: It's gone. It's not there anymore. This question is reopen. I'm feeling like Maya's dev took over blender and is trashing it.

Comment: does it answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169121/2d-falloff-button-gone-in-2-82-7