# 2d falloff button gone in 2.82.7

Tags: weight-painting

The 2d falloff button for weightpainting pass through seems to be gone in the new update, now there's a button which i found worked the first time i used it but now doesn't called frontface falloff, I am currently trying to weightpaint a mesh that has several layers of mesh beneath it, and manually weightpainting each layer or vertex grouping every layer seems a bit overboard, I've tried using x-ray as well and it still wont pass through, front faces only was also unchecked and checked and did nothing.

https://i.gyazo.com/54cc1f75c99fa6fc907b69ec16304a04.gif

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem after downloading this new Blender version.

If you open this *Falloff* menu, then there is that *Falloff Shape*. 
Changing it from *Sphere* to *Project* work for me.

Comment: thank you so much you've saved me so much heart ache haha